# Why is round() returning a wrong answer and how do I fix it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a simple challenge that requires the code to return numbers (floats) rounded to `1` decimal point(s). The code is actually working but it seems that `round()` is not returning the correct result.

For example, the answer to one of the test cases I'm getting is `45357.45`. When rounded to the first decimal, this should be `45357.5`. But using `round()` is still returning `45357.4`. I tested with the following numbers and I'm getting mixed results:

```py
# Correct
print(round(5.45, 1))
5.5

# Incorrect
print(round(5674.45, 1))
5674.4
```

Why would this happen and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `print(5674.45, 1)` Did you mean `print(round(5674.45, 1))` ?

Comment: If you write 5674.45 in your code, you get a number equal to around `5674.449999...`. Because floating point numbers are approximations.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. My brain is fried and I need some nap :)